# .txt Log File Data Extraction Output to CSV with REGEX

Tags: powershell, csv, logging, extract

I have asked this question before to which LotPings came up with a perfect result. When speaking to the user this relates to I only got half the information in the first place!

Knowing now exactly what is required I will explain the scenario again...

Things to be bear in mind:

- Terminal will always be A followed by 3 digits i.e. A123
- User ID is at the top of the log file and only appears once, will always start with 89 and be six digits long. the line will always start SELECTED FOR OPERATOR 89XXXX
- There are two Date patterns in the file (one is the date of search the other DOB) each needs extracting to separate columns. Not all records have a DOB and some only have the year.
- Enquirer doesn't always begin with a 'C' and needs the whole proceeding line.
- The search result always has 'Enquiry' and then extraction after that.

Here is the log file

```
L      TRANSACTIONS LOGGED FROM 01/05/2018 0001 TO 31/05/2018 2359
        SELECTED FOR OPERATOR  891234

START                 TERMINAL    USER        ENQUIRER                    TERMINAL IP
========================================================================================================================
01/05/18 1603       A555        CART87565       46573 RBCO NPC SERVICES GW/10/0043                           
        SEARCH ENQUIRY               RECORD NO : S48456/06P     CHAPTER CODE =   
                                 RECORD DISPLAYED : S48853/98D

                                  PRINT REQUESTED : SINGLE RECORD
========================================================================================================================
03/05/18 1107       A555        CERT16574       BTD/54/1786 16475                                    
        REF ENQUIRY                  DHF ID : 58/94710W     CHAPTER CODE =   
                                 RECORD DISPLAYED : S585988/84H
========================================================================================================================
24/05/18 1015       A555        CERT15473       19625 CBRS DDS SERVICES NM/18/0199                           

        IMAGE ENQUIRY                      NAME : TREVOR SMITH CHAPTER CODE =  

                                    DATE OF BIRTH :   /  /1957
========================================================================================================================
24/05/18 1025       A555        CERT15473       15325 CBRS DDS SERVICES NM/12/0999                           
        REF ENQUIRY                  DDS ID : 04/102578R     CHAPTER CODE =  
========================================================================================================================
```

Here is an example of the log file and what needs to be extracted and under what header.

[image]

To a CSV looking like this

[image]

The PowerShell Script LotPings has done works perfectly, I just need User ID to be extracted from the top line, to account for not all records having DOB and there being more than one type of enquiry i.e. Ref Enquiry, Search Enquiry, Image Enquiry.

```bsh
$FileIn   = '.\SO_51209341_data.txt'
$TodayCsv = '.\SO_51209341_data.csv'

$RE1 = [RegEx]'(?m)(?<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}) (?<Time>\d{4}) +(?<Terminal>A\d{3}) +(?<User>C[A-Z0-9]+) +(?<Enquirer>.*)$'
$RE2 = [RegEx]'\s+SEARCH REF\s+NAME : (?<Enquiry>.+?) (PAGE|CHAPTER) CODE ='
$RE3 = [RegEx]'\s+DATE OF BIRTH : (?<DOB>[0-9 /]+?/\d{4})'

$Sections = (Get-Content $FileIn -Raw) -split "={30,}`r?`n" -ne ''

$Csv = ForEach($Section in $Sections){
    $Row= @{} | Select-Object Date, Time, Terminal, User, Enquirer, Enquiry, DOB
    $Cnt = 0
    if ($Section -match $RE1) {
        ++$Cnt
        $Row.Date     = $Matches.Date
        $Row.Time     = $Matches.Time
        $Row.Terminal = $Matches.Terminal
        $Row.User     = $Matches.User
        $Row.Enquirer = $Matches.Enquirer.Trim()
    }
    if ($Section -match $RE2) {
        ++$Cnt
        $Row.Enquiry  = $Matches.Enquiry
    }
    if ($Section -match $RE3){
        ++$Cnt
        $Row.DOB      = $Matches.DOB
    }
    if ($Cnt -eq 3) {$Row}
}

$csv | Format-Table
$csv | Export-Csv $Todaycsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `Select-String '(?<=FOR OPERATOR\s+)\d+' | Select-Object -Expand Mateches | Select-Object -Expand Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such precise data the first answer could have been:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\12\SO_51311417.ps1
$FileIn   = '.\SO_51311417_data.txt'
$TodayCsv = '.\SO_51311417_data.csv'

$RE0 = [RegEx]'SELECTED FOR OPERATOR\s+(?<UserID>\d{6})'
$RE1 = [RegEx]'(?m)(?<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}) (?<Time>\d{4}) +(?<Terminal>A\d{3}) +(?<Enquirer>.*)$'
$RE2 = [RegEx]'\s+(SEARCH|REF|IMAGE) ENQUIRY\s+(?<SearchResult>.+?)\s+(PAGE|CHAPTER) CODE'
$RE3 = [RegEx]'\s+DATE OF BIRTH : (?<DOB>[0-9 /]+?/\d{4})'

$Sections = (Get-Content $FileIn -Raw) -split "={30,}`r?`n" -ne ''
$UserID = "n/a"
$Csv = ForEach($Section in $Sections){
    If ($Section -match $RE0){
        $UserID = $Matches.UserID
    } Else {
        $Row= @{} | Select-Object Date,Time,Terminal,UserID,Enquirer,SearchResult,DOB
        $Cnt = 0
        If ($Section -match $RE1){
            $Row.Date     = $Matches.Date
            $Row.Time     = $Matches.Time
            $Row.Terminal = $Matches.Terminal
            $Row.Enquirer = $Matches.Enquirer.Trim()
            $Row.UserID   = $UserID
        }
        If ($Section -match $RE2){
            $Row.SearchResult  = $Matches.SearchResult
        }
        If ($Section -match $RE3){
            $Row.DOB      = $Matches.DOB
        }
        $Row
    }
}

$csv | Format-Table
$csv | Export-Csv $Todaycsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output

```
Date     Time Terminal UserID Enquirer                                           SearchResult           DOB
----     ---- -------- ------ --------                                           ------------           ---
01/05/18 1603 A555     891234 CART87565       46573 RBCO NPC SERVICES GW/10/0043 RECORD NO : S48456/06P
03/05/18 1107 A555     891234 CERT16574       BTD/54/1786 16475                  DHF ID : 58/94710W
24/05/18 1015 A555     891234 CERT15473       19625 CBRS DDS SERVICES NM/18/0199 NAME : TREVOR SMITH      /  /1957
24/05/18 1025 A555     891234 CERT15473       15325 CBRS DDS SERVICES NM/12/0999 DDS ID : 04/102578R
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Are you able give me any advice on where I could learn more about PowerShell scripting? Either documentation and or courses. I could see me being asked to do more of these and want to try and a lot of this myself!

Comment: Well 40years IT-background does help, but to be honest the most I learned about powershell was here on [SO] helping other people. The logic in the script is mostly based on the Regular Expressions with alternations and named capture groups - read [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and try on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried so hard to get it working myself, but because I am a real beginner at PowerShell I didn't really know how some of the script worked so I will start learning from the ground up and hopefully I can build on that.